# JSF 2.0 Get list of client id in managed bean

Tags: jsf-2, ajax4jsf

Is there a way to get the list of all client id of the contents of a particular div inside managed bean? I have the client id of the div. I have to call `resetValue(...)` on each component inside the div.

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(...)`  will give me a single component if I provide the client id. I do not want to use it because I have a lot of components inside the div and this will have around 100 lines of code just to reset one div.

Is a way I can get the list of cient id so that I can iterate over this list and reset all the components? I am open to other approaches as well, as long as I can reset all components inside the div. 
My bean is managed by Spring (`scope("view")`). I use a `a4j:commandButton` to submit values to this bean. When I load the page again, I see the previously submitted values, which is incorrect. I tried `resetValue(...)` on one component inside the div after submission and it did reset the values of the component.
Any help is appreciated.

Code sample:

xhtml:

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="EditSeaPage">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="editSeaContainer"
    rendered="#{seaBean.showEditSea}" layout="block"
    styleClass="switch-section">

        <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputLabel value="#{messageSource.sea_label}" />
        <h:inputText id="updateSeaCode"
         value="#{seaBean.seaUIDTO.seaCode}"
         styleClass="user-detail">
         <a4j:ajax />
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <a4j:commandButton id="confirmUpdateSeaCode" execute="@this"
     action="#{seaBean.updateSeaCode}" render="parentContainer"/>
</a4j:outputPanel>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

Parent xhtml:

```
<a4j:commandLink id="editSeaCode" value="edit"  onclick="hideMe()" render="editPortContainer"/>
```

Bean:

```
public String updateSeaCode() {
//does update
UIInput input = (UIInput) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("updateSeaCode");
  input.resetValue();
   //This works. But I have around 20 input components in the above XHTML and can't write the //above code for each component
}
```

I just added a skeleton of what I am doing. How can I make sure the view gets updated when the call ends? To give me some more details, here is how it works: I have an `edit` link, which is an `a4j:commandLink`. On click of this link, I hide the link and display the `editSeaContainer`. If you see there is a rendered attribute. As soon as I click on the `edit` link I hide the link using `jQuery` and I make an `a4j:jsFunction` to set the boolean property to true so that this page is rendered. After the `a4j:jsFunction` I call a fetch method to retrieve the contents of this xhtml. By the time the method finishes, the boolean is set and the 'render' attribute renders the page. Everything is fine till here. But the input values do not update with the fetched values.

Thanks.

Comment: If you work with Ajax (as it seems to be) and you're rendering the list in your response, just clear the mapped value fields in your bean. This means kind of `client.setValue("")`.

Comment: If you meant clearing the values in the bean, I did that already and that is not helping. The values are correctly populated in the bean, but the view still shows the old values.

Comment: Then that's because view doesn't get updated when ajax call ends. But as you don't provide a further example of your code I can't infer what's going wrong.

Comment: Use `render` attribute of `a4j:commandButton`: <a4j:commandButton id="confirmUpdateSeaCode" action="#{seaBean.updateSeaCode}" render="EditSeaPage" />

Comment: I just edited the piece of code so that you get a clearer picture of what I am doing. I used the 'render' attribute but that only helps in rendering the 'div/a4j:outputPanel'. That still does not help in updating the input component values.

Comment: I also observed that all the output components render the values correctly. The problem is only with input components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as JSF goes, the most straightforward way to get the list of ids of the children of a component is with the `UIComponent#getChildren()` and then iterating on the returned list to perform the reset:

```
    HtmlPanelGrid yourDiv = facesContext.getViewRoot().findComponent("theDivId");//facesContext is an instance of FacesContext
    List<UIComponent> children = yourDiv.getChildren();

        for(UIComponent child: children){

          if(child instanceof UIInput){ //resetValue is applicable only to input comps.
               ((UIInput)child).resetValue();
          }    
        }
```

A more sweeping way to reset the values on an entire page is to call the same method on the `UIViewRoot` instance associated with that page as in:

```
    FacesContext ctxt = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    UIViewRoot viewRoot = ctxt.getViewRoot();
    viewRoot.resetValues(ctxt,listOfIds);
```

Where `listOfIds` refers to a `Collection<String>` of clientIds belonging to components you want to perform a reset on. Obviously, this requires you to have the component ids beforehand.

---

JSF 2.2 has introduced the `<f:resetValues/>` tag (and `resetValues` attribute on the `<f:ajax/>` tag) to solve this specific problem

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. I use JSF 2.1.13 and can't try `<f:resetValues/>`, though that seems more attractive.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the syntax is incorrect in the first code snippet. `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("theDivId");`